# Assign percentage of space to child of child components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to build a react app. There will be a side bar and then a main section. In the diagram the side bar is on the left, and the main section is everything on the right. I want to side bar to be 35% of the total screen, and the main section to be the remaining 65%. So in my app.js file, I have two divs, one for the side and another for the main. In the css, I have `flex: .35` and `flex: .65`, respectfully. I change the background color of each div, and the space is correctly assigned.

So far so good, now I'm having troubles with the flex stuff the main section sub components. In the main section, I want the top header to be 20%, the middle section 60% and the bottom header 20%. So I created 3 divs for each component. I then assigned `flex: .20`, `flex: .60` and `flex: .20`. I then changed the background color for each component, so I can see the space allocated. And nothing showed up. Can you please explain how to align a div to have the correct % of space?

[image]

Comment: Please add some code to further explain your concept.

Comment: Add your code please, you can't expect someone to write everything from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried my luck and I found a solution by using `display: flex;` and `display: grid;` together.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35vw 65vw;
}

.grid-left {
    background: #f2a154;
}

.grid-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    background: #314e52;
}

.flexbox-bar {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 65vw;
}

.flexbox-body {
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #f7f6e7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-left">Side Bar</div>
        <div class="grid-right">
            <div class="flexbox-bar">Header</div>
            <div class="flexbox-body">Body</div>
            <div class="flexbox-bar">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You are using a `.grid-container` in order to create two columns by using `display: grid;` and define two `grid-template-columns: 35vw 65vw;` with the specific width.

The first grid element refers to the sidebar, and the right element refers to the main section.

The right element will get `display: flex;` so that it turns into a flexbox; it also gets `flex-flow: column wrap;` to define the flow direction as a column so that the content is beneath each other.

The rest is just simply giving the element a specific `width` and `height` as you want.

It's a solution for just using HTML and CSS.

Comment: You are awesome, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the answer.